# how to delete all rows after 1000 rows in postgresql Table

Tags: postgresql

I have huge Database with 15 tables.
I need to make light version of that and leave only first 1000 rows in each table based on DESC Date. I did try to find on google how to do that but nothing really works.

It will be perfect it there will be automated way to go through each table and leave only 1000 rows.
But If I need to do that manually with each table it will be fine as well.

Thank you,

Comment: Write a DELETE query with a WHERE clause preserving the 1000 records you want to keep. You may also read [mcve] and [ask] and update your post to provide more details.

Comment: I think you are asking, how do I prune 15 tables' records to preserve only the most recent 1000 records in each.  Can we see an example of two tables that shows things like the "date" data type and naming conventions?  Also, are there ties?  Could there be 2 or more records that have the exact same date?

Comment: Yes. I just need example of Query to leave first 1000 rows. Each table have different Columns, so It should be some general command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So solution is:

```
DELETE FROM "table" WHERE "date" < now() - interval '1 year';
```

That way it will delete all data from table where Date is older that 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

This looks positively awful, but maybe it's a starting point from which you can build.

```
with cte as (
  select mod_date, row_number() over (order by mod_date desc) as rn
  from table1
),
min_date as (
  select mod_date
  from cte
  where rn = 1000
)
delete from table1 t1
where t1.mod_date < (select mod_date from min_date)
```